# used space in a new empty partition

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ext4

I've created an extended partition (ext4) on one of my hard-disks. here is what it looks like:

```
Filesystem             Size   Used  Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sdc5              158G   5,9G   144G   4% /media/YAHSI
```

why on earth there am i losing **8,1 GB** space? when you add `used` & `avail` you don't get the size.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are reserved for root and privileged processes. Run `sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sdc5` to free them up for regular users.

From the man page:

> Reserving some number  of  filesystem
>                 blocks for use by privileged processes is done to avoid
>   filesystem fragmentation, and to allow system  daemons,  such  as 
>   syslogd(8),  to continue to function correctly after
>   non-privileged
>                 processes are prevented from writing to  the  filesystem.
>   Normally, the default percentage of reserved blocks is 5%.

If you are just using the partition for extra storage, you don't need the reserved space.