# Ubuntu 18.04 Incorrectly Stating 100% Disk Space Used

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, 18.04

I woke up to a red exclamation mark on my computer.  It warned I had only 800k of disk space remaining in /home .  I went into terminal and did " df -h " to confirm this.

```
/dev/sdb5       825G  783G   13M 100% /home
```

That is 42gb that remains.  Did Ubuntu go on strike while I was sleeping and refuse to use this?  Is the4re a logical explanation?  Or did I just discover an error with Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: You might want to see:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/37094/used-space-in-a-new-empty-partition  You might also want to see the inode as `df -i` if the inodes are full then the drive will appear full.

Comment: OK.  This makes some sense